# Java Persistence Criteria fetch collection using multiselect

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, jpa, criteria-api

I have a class consists of id and a list of vitals with other attributes

```
public class Patient
{
    private Integer Id;
    private String FirstName;
    private String LastName;
    private List<Vital> Vitals;

    public Patient(Integer id, List<Vital> vitals)
    {
        this.Id = id;
        this.setVitals(vitals);
    }

    main()
    {
        Session session = Hibernate.openSession();
        CriteriaBuilder cb = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Patient> cq = cb.createQuery(Patient.class);
        Root<Patient> root = cq.from(Patient.class);
        cq.multiselect(root.get("Id"), root.get("Vitals"));
        List<Patient> patients = session.createQuery(cq).getResultList();

        session.close();
    }

}
```

But the mentioned code produces an exception of undefined proper constructor

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Unable to locate appropriate constructor on class [com.bk.Patient]. Expected arguments are: int, java.util.Collection [select new com.bk.Patient(generatedAlias0.Id, generatedAlias0.Vitals) from com.bk.Patient as generatedAlias0]
> at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:138)

If I change my constructor to

```
    public PatientEncounter(Integer id, java.util.Collection vitals)
    {
        this.Id = id;
//      this.setVitals(vitals);
    }
```

The exception converts to

> Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
> Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.

Following these links [Question1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38976618/jpa-criteria-multiselect-with-fetch) and [Question2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60356537/hibernate-criteria-multi-select-query-with-join)

```
    CriteriaQuery<Tuple> cq = cb.createTupleQuery();
        
    Root<Patient> root = cq.from(Patient.class);
        
    Path<String> namePath = root.get("Vitals");
    Path<Integer> idPath = root.get("Id");
        
    cq.multiselect(idPath , namePath);
        
    session.createQuery(cq).getResultList().stream();
```

Also produces the same exception

> Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
> Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

**P.S: If I fetch only attributes, the code works fine. Only fetching collection results in exceptions**

Comment: Is there any need to use criteria?  is there any dynamic query issues?  if not you can use join fetch attributes

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to select a collection. You can only select elements of it. What you probably want there is to create a fetch for the collection i.e.

```
    Session session = Hibernate.openSession();
    CriteriaBuilder cb = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Patient> cq = cb.createQuery(Patient.class);
    Root<Patient> root = cq.from(Patient.class);
    root.fetch("Vitals");
    List<Patient> patients = session.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
```